# How to check if there is any overlapping in array of range object using Joi

Tags: javascript, json, validation, object, joi

I have a object with one of key having array of range object.

```
// this is valid object because startRank and endRank are not overlapping in all object
var object_1 = {
    "prizeDistribution": [
        {
            "startRank": 1,
            "endRank": 4,
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "startRank": 4,
            "endRank": 11,
            "value": 7
        },
        {
            "startRank": 11,
            "endRank": 21,
            "value": 4
        },
        {
            "startRank": 21,
            "endRank": 51,
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "startRank": 51,
            "endRank": 101,
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
}

// this is invalid object because startRank and endRank are overlapping
var object_2 = {
    "prizeDistribution": [
        {
            "startRank": 1,
            "endRank": 4,
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "startRank": 3,
            "endRank": 11,
            "value": 7
        }
    ]
}

var schema = Joi.object({
    "prizeDistribution": Joi.array().items({
        "startRank": Joi.number().integer().required(),
        "endRank": Joi.number().integer().required(),
        "value": Joi.number().integer().required()                                         
    })
})
```

How can I validate such array of range object using [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to achieve this through  [Array.unique](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.7#arrayuniquecomparator-options) check in Joi. Basically mark an array item as duplicate if it falls in the range of any  other array item.

Something like below could help.

```
var schema = Joi.object({
      prizeDistribution: Joi.array()
        .items(
          Joi.object({
            startRank: Joi.number()
              .integer()
              .required(),
            endRank: Joi.number()
              .integer()
              .required(),
            value: Joi.number()
              .integer()
              .required()
          })
        )
        .unique((a, b) => {
          return (
            (a.startRank > b.startRank && a.startRank < b.endRank) ||
            (a.endRank > b.startRank && a.endRank < b.endRank)
          );
        })
    });
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/@nithinthampi/joi-array-validation)

Answer (score 0):

little small and better

```
var schema = Joi.object({
      prizeDistribution: Joi.array()
        .items(
          Joi.object({
            startRank: Joi.number().integer().required(),
            endRank: Joi.number().integer().required(),
            value: Joi.number().integer().required()
          })
        ).unique((a, b) => (b.endRank > a.startRank) && (b.startRank < a.endRank))
    });
```